# Adding loading bar to navigation controller | Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, loading

I'm attempting to add this loading bar library to my navigation controller bar. Unfortunately, nothing is appearing. What am I doing wrong and how can I make this work?

```
import GradientLoadingBar

class ViewController: UIViewController {

   fileprivate let gradientLoadingBar = GradientLoadingBar()

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      self.navigationController?.delegate = self
      self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(gradientLoadingBar.gradientActivityIndicatorView)
      gradientLoadingBar.fadeIn()
   }

}
```

Note: If I don't attempt to add the loading bar to the navigation bar, it works fine, but it automatically places the loading bar in the middle of the navigation bar (splitting it in half). I'd like to create a function that I can call from anywhere in my app that I simply tell it [On] or [Off] and it shows the loading bar on my navigation controller bar accordingly.

GradientLoadingBar: [documentation](https://github.com/fxm90/GradientLoadingBar)

Answer (score 0):

Did you check [this example](https://github.com/fxm90/GradientLoadingBar/blob/main/Example/Example/Scenes/NavigationBarExample/NavigationBarExampleViewController.swift), from the documentation?

Maybe you missed to add the constraints and set gradientLoadingBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false